# Problem with Symbolic links in PHP\Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, laravel-7, shared-hosting

I am using Laravel 7 on Direct admin. I don't actually have access to Command Line/Terminal, and I need a Symbolic link of Storage.

I have Tried:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

and also:

```
symlink('/domains/MyProject.com/LaravelFolder/storage/app/public', '/domains/MyProject.com/public_html');
```

But I am receiving this Error:

```
symlink() has been disabled for security reasons
```

My LaravelFolder is Placed before public_html.

***UPDATE: I realized that the Hosting company disabled this function; I asked them to enable it, But They say: it is impossible. Do you know an alternative way to do that?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Old Solution**

But I finally Solved This, It seems little bit stupid but it works:

In Ubuntu Linux I tried to create a symlink like the storage symbolic link in Laravel, with the following Command:

```
ln -s ../laravelFolder/storage/app/public storage
```

and then I compressed this symbolic link and uploaded to my public_html Folder and it works.
I hope it will be Helpful..

**2022 UPDATE (New Solution)**

In such cases that your projects production environment is a Linux server and you are developing your project on Windows I offer you to set up a **WSL** (Windows Subsystem for Linux) development environment.

This way you can simply use Linux terminal to creating a symbolic link with the following command:

```
// change laravelFolder with your laravel folder name
ln -s ../laravelFolder/storage/app/public storage
```

**[Here is Microsoft's quick guide to install and use WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `public` disk's root path to point directly public folder. Consider the below snippet;

```php
/** /config/filesystems.php */

'disks' => [
    // ...
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('storage'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    // ...
],
```

Note that this is not a best practice.

Comment: Interestingly enough I needed just that to have Laravel running via Octane (swoole) within a Docker container (Laravel Sail) serve static assets that are symlinked within the storage path.
If the public storage path remains symlinked this would result in symlinks within symlinks - Octane does not like that at all. Moved the root directly to the public folder and it worked nicely.